# Expectation of a distribution when the CDF changes over the domain?

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

I have to find the expectation of X and the variance. 
A random variable X has the following CDF:

$$
F(x)=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{e^x}{2},\quad x<0 \\ 
\frac{1}{2},\quad 0\le x < 1\\
1\ -\ \frac{1}{2} e^{-0.5(x-1)}, \quad  x \ge 1\\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

The CDF and PDF for the last part is similar to the exponential distribution. However, I wasnt able to arrive at the expected value using the simple formula for the expectation of the distribution since it is defined only for a part of the domain.

So far, I have got the following:
\begin{array}{ll}
E[X] \ = \ \frac{-1}{2}  \\
\text{by integrating:}  \quad \frac{1}{2}xe^x&  \\
E[X^2] \ = \ 1 \\
\text{by integrating:} \quad \frac{1}{2}x^2e^x&  \\
\end{array}

for the second part, I arrived at these:

\begin{array}{ll}
E[X] \ = \ \frac{3}{2}  \\
\text{by integrating:}  \quad \frac{1}{4}xe^{-0.5(x-1)}  \\
E[X^2] \ = \ \frac{13}{2} \\
\text{by integrating:} \quad \frac{1}{4}x^2e^{-0.5(x-1)}  \\
\end{array}

Have I gone about doing this the correct way? Do you just add up the expectations to get $$E[X] \ = \ 1 $$
for the entire distribution? And likewise for X^2?

Apologies for the formatting. This is the first time I'm posting and I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to observe is that $F$ is continuous, since $$\frac{e^0}{2} = \frac{1}{2} = 1 - \frac{1}{2}e^{-(1-1)/2}.$$

So the density is obtained through differentiation:

$$f_X(x) = F_X'(x) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{e^x}{2}, & x < 0 \\
0, & 0 \le x < 1 \\
\frac{1}{4}e^{-(x-1)/2}, & x \ge 1.
\end{cases}$$

It is worth noting that what this means is that $X \not\in [0,1)$.  We can now just integrate accordingly:

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[X^k] 
&= \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty x^k f_X(x) \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{x=-\infty}^0 x^k e^x \, dx + \frac{1}{4} \int_{x=1}^\infty x^k e^{-(x-1)/2} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{u=0}^\infty (-u)^k e^{-u} \, du + \frac{1}{2} \int_{v=0}^\infty (2v+1)^k e^{-v} \, dv \\
&= \frac{(-1)^k}{2} \int_{u=0}^\infty u^k e^{-u} \, du + 2^{k-1} \int_{v=0}^\infty (v + \tfrac{1}{2})^k e^{-v} \, dv.
\end{align}$$

The first integral is just the familiar gamma function $\Gamma(k+1)$.  The second is an incomplete gamma function but since we are only interested in $k \in \{1, 2\}$, we calculate it for just these two cases:

$$\int_{v=0}^\infty (v + \tfrac{1}{2})e^{-v} \, dv = \Gamma(2) + \frac{1}{2} \Gamma(1) = \frac{3}{2},$$
and
$$\int_{v=0}^\infty (v + \tfrac{1}{2})^2 e^{-v} \, dv = \int_{v=0}^\infty (v^2 e^{-v} + v e^{-v} + \tfrac{1}{4}e^{-v}) \, dv = \Gamma(3) + \Gamma(2) + \frac{1}{4}\Gamma(1) = 2 + 1 + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{13}{4}.$$
Therefore,
$$\operatorname{E}[X] = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2} = 1, \\
\operatorname{E}[X^2] = \frac{1}{2}\Gamma(3) + 2 \cdot \frac{13}{4} = 1 + \frac{13}{2} = \frac{15}{2},$$
from which we obtain
$$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2 = \frac{15}{2} - 1^2 = \frac{13}{2}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for that detailed explanation! That cleared up everything.

Comment: @Shreesha If you found the answer useful, please accept and/or upvote it.